# Remove whole tag from XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am creating a script to sanitize tags and attributes from a XML file I need to load.

Structure example:

```
<Cli TipCli="1" NmCli="client_name">
    <EndEtnCli EmaiCli="client_email"/>
</Cli>
```

In case the attribute `EmailCli` is empty, I want to remove the whole tag `<EndEtnCli/>`.

I've followed some tutorials here and got into this code below, it's not showing any error, but it does not work at all.

What am I missing?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import date

tree = ET.parse('src/021/sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for client in root:
  # sanitize email from client
  el = client.find('EndEtnCli')
  if el.attrib.get('EmaiCli') == '': client.remove(el)

currentDate = date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
tree.write(f'src/021/test_{ currentDate }', encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>
     <Cli TipCli="1" NmCli="client_name1">
       <EndEtnCli EmaiCli=""/>
     </Cli>  
     <Cli TipCli="2" NmCli="client_name2">
       <EndEtnCli/>
     </Cli>
     <Cli TipCli="3" NmCli="client_name3">
       <EndEtnCli EmaiCli="client_email"/>
     </Cli>
     </r>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
cli_lst = root.findall('.//Cli')
for cli in cli_lst:
    child = cli.find('./EndEtnCli')
    email_cli = child.attrib.get('EmaiCli')
    if email_cli is None or len(email_cli) == 0:
        cli.remove(child)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<r>
     <Cli NmCli="client_name1" TipCli="1">
       </Cli>  
     <Cli NmCli="client_name2" TipCli="2">
       </Cli>
     <Cli NmCli="client_name3" TipCli="3">
       <EndEtnCli EmaiCli="client_email" />
     </Cli>
 </r>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @balderman, it actually worked! Could you just explain why it worked in this case? I still cant figure out why my code didnt work in comparison to yours

Comment: The main difference is that my code cover the case where `EmailCli` does not exist at all. If my answer helps you - feel free to vote up.